# How to Query Large Data from Salesforce using jitterbit

Tags: salesforce, etl, jitterbit

I am working on a requirement where I need to transfer all Salesforce records From  Object A to  Object B for this I need to use only the Jitterbit ETL Tool.

In  Object A total of 40+million records, 
In the source  I cannot use a write-back option while querying the Records. thought of using a  checkbox or something but it will affect other integrations based on object A If I had that it would be easy I could query only 1million each time.

Explored different Options:

- I thought of querying the id's and do order by and storing the last record id and do order by again I could repeat the process but after 3million records ids are not consistent.
- finally, I decided to go with the query every month on Created Date to query the records.
- I am storing the source record Id in Target as an external Id so that I won't insert duplicates.

Is there any better approach for this? did anyone has done this scenario before please let me know?

It would be a great help Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using jitterbit dataloader?

Comment: I can't edit the excel since It has huge data of 40million and I need to add 2more columns. So I am using jitterbit script and used Last_n_days in SOQL Query,I am seeing an issue where same data coming over and over again Ex:: CreatedDate>=LAST_N_DAYS:367 and CreatedDate<=LAST_N_DAYS:367 I see the same records for CreatedDate>=LAST_N_DAYS:368 and CreatedDate<=LAST_N_DAYS:368 Can someone help here what am I doing wrong.